# Swift boundingRect returns different values for same input on playground and actual project

Tags: swift, string, swift-playground

I'm not perfectly sure why boundingRect returns incorrect value in some case such as when a text ends closed to its maximum width. It works fine on all other cases though.

Here's example.

```
func snap(_ x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
  let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
  return ceil(x * scale) / scale
}

func snap(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: snap(point.x), y: snap(point.y))
}

func snap(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: snap(size.width), height: snap(size.height))
}

func snap(_ rect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
  return CGRect(origin: snap(rect.origin), size: snap(rect.size))
}


extension String {
  func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, attributes: [String: AnyObject]) -> CGRect {
    let options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading]
    let rect = self.boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    return snap(rect)
  }

  func size(fits size: CGSize, font: UIFont, maximumNumberOfLines: Int = 0) -> CGSize {
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
    var size = self.boundingRect(with: size, attributes: attributes).size
    if maximumNumberOfLines > 0 {
      size.height = min(size.height, CGFloat(maximumNumberOfLines) * font.lineHeight)
    }
    return size
  }

  func width(with font: UIFont, maximumNumberOfLines: Int = 0) -> CGFloat {
    let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    return self.size(fits: size, font: font, maximumNumberOfLines: maximumNumberOfLines).width
  }

  func height(fits width: CGFloat, font: UIFont, maximumNumberOfLines: Int = 0) -> CGFloat {
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    return self.size(fits: size, font: font, maximumNumberOfLines: maximumNumberOfLines).height
  }

  func height(fits width: CGFloat, attributes: [String:AnyObject]) -> CGFloat {
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    return self.boundingRect(with: size, attributes: attributes).height
  }
}
```

with above extension and methods, I ran below code in playground.

```
let str = "ありがとうございます。スマホ専用のページがなくても反映できるかはエンジンにご確認いたします。"
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
let attributes = [
  NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
]
let height = str.height(fits: 320, attributes: attributes)
print("calculated height: ", height)
```

and it returned 54.

However, when I ran same code in simple project (single view controller, copied and pasted above into `viewDidLoad:` in `ViewController`, it returned 36 (missing one line height). Any idea why this two behave differently with same input?

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on multiple simulators for iOS 10.3 and they all give me the value of 54.0 for calculated height.

You didn't specify which version of iOS you are using, so perhaps that is significant.

Also, print the font that is used in your app and in your playground.  For UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15) I get .SFUIText in both.

Comment: have you tried on device? apparently it returns 36 on my device.. and it seemed like only happen on unicode language

Comment: oh btw you should've test on iphone 7 plus size

Comment: I've also tested on simulator iphone 7 plus, and i found that it seemed like font size became different from simulator vs device for japanese characters

Comment: i tested on device using playground on ipad but only english.